# finding active threads for regionserver(HBase)

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Is there way to find all active threads to particular regionServer in Hbase?
I want to see, what is causing bottleneck to particular node.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the RegionServer find the Java Processes of interest to you - meaning everything HBase related. The jvm ships a handy utility to do this, called 'jps'. Here is some example output:

```
jps -l
18863 sun.tools.jps.Jps
2584 /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Once you have the processes you need, use 'jstack' to get thread dumps.

```
jstack <pid> >> threaddump.log
```

Also check the HBase documentations [Troubles](http://hbase.apache.org/book/trouble.rs.html)
 section if your problem is already known.

For in depth investigation with jstack [Eclipse.org](http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock#jstackSeries_--_jstack_sampling_in_fixed_time_intervals_.28tested_on_Linux.29) has a nice little script for taking jstack snapshots in fixed time intervals. It may be good for investigating deadlocks (just in case this is your assumption).

Comment: One more thing, cat /proc/{RS-PID}/status ,show Threads=131 . So what is this thread ?